# Could not find sqlite3-1.3.9 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am running the following stack :

==> ruby -v ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]

==> gem -v 2.2.2

==> rails -v Rails 4.1.0

==> bundle -v Bundler version 1.6.2

on ubuntu running apache

And I am getting the following error :

Could not find sqlite3-1.3.9 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Comment: There is the versio 1.3.9 of the gem sqlite3. See here: https://rubygems.org/gems/sqlite3/versions. So just verify you connection to rubygems.org. Also make sure that you have specified gem source. Then try to install the gem either with gem utility: `gem install sqlite3 --version 1.3.9`, or just download the gem manually, and then install it : `gem install ./sqlite3-1.3.9.gem`

Comment: I have a similar issue - rails 4.1, ruby 2.1.1p76, rbenv to manage ruby versions and I have run bundle install, deleted Gemfile.lock, still have the same issue... One by one, each gem goes through a "Could not find" - I have done gem install <gemname> for each, and then a different gem is not found...

Answer (score 0):

Have you run bundler from your application directory? eg. 'bundle install'?